# How to check size of image from upload files control before I save it to the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have file upload control in ASP.NET C#. I need to check if image that user would like to upload is smaller than 2Mb and then I would like to save it on server. 
I know that after adding a photo I can use such construction:

> ```
> fileUpload.SaveAs(image.jpg);
> var fileLength = new FileInfo(image.jpg).Length;
> ```

but what if I need to check the size of photo before I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the file size, you can access the ContentLength property of the PostedFile propery:

```
fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `ContentLength`

```
int _FileSize = file.ContentLength;
```

You can see more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.postedfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) !

Answer (score 1):

you can check it using javascript

```
<script>
function UploadFile()
   {             
     var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
     if (file.size > 2097152) { alert("File is too big..."); return false; }
   }
</script>
```

or you can check it in your method as
 `var filesize=image.ContentLength;`

Answer (score 1):

This will get the size in bytes of the file to upload.

```
int maxSize = 12345;
int sizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;

if(sizeInBytez > maxSize)
{
    // do something
}
```

Please do check as well your web.config for the settings above, this will control the maximum upload size for your site. (In this case close to 5MB)

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="44288000"/> 
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```